# change bars chart granularity to Days/Month/Week by report user

Tags: looker-studio

i have few simple charts where each bar represent day according to date rage control I've added.
i want that the report user will be able to change aggregation
so instead of each bar that represent day,i want each bar that represent month or week

is there anyway i can do that in Google Data Studio ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have date as Dimension in the Data tab to the right.
You can 'drill down' by selecting the switch just below.
Add the date dimension again then edit this new dimension and change type
to Date/time and select the granularity such as week or month.

Then in view mode there will be up and down arrows in the top right of the plot which allows you to change view to different drill down options (week/month etc) which you selected in the data tab.